# Adapting an OpenCL kernel to OpenGL-only

Tags: opengl, webgl, opencl, shader

I would like to figure out if there's a way to adapt the following OpenCL approach to OpenGL only. What this OpenCL kernel does is go through several buffers generated by the host and copied to the device memory to know what graphics to render to the OpenGL texture `srgb`. The CPU generates those buffers for each frame to render, enqueues the copying of those buffers to the GPU and enqueues the execution of the following kernel, which writes to the OpenGL texture while it is temporarily owned by OpenCL, and then naturally when this is all done OpenGL displays the texture on the screen. An iteration of this OpenCL kernel focuses entirely on fully generating and writing a single pixel in one pass only, it very much operates on a per-pixel basis and for every pixel of the texture in the same way with the same parameters and data to work with.

```
kernel void draw_queue_srgb_kernel(global float *paramlist, global int *poslist, global int *entrylist, global uchar *data_cl, write_only image2d_t srgb, const int sector_w, const int sector_size)
{
    const int2 p = (int2) (get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1));
    float4 pv;      // pixel value (linear)

    // this computes the pixel value
    pv = draw_queue(paramlist, poslist, entrylist, data_cl, sector_w, sector_size);

    // this writes the pixel value to the texture
    write_imagef(srgb, p, linear_to_srgb(pv));
}
```

What is the best way to have a similar approach work only with OpenGL? I need the flexibility to provide arrays that are not textures in any way (they're more similar to lists of indices and parameters used for drawing) and to do a lot of math for each pixel (I use `sqrt()`, `sin()`, `exp()` and `erf()` a lot for instance), on the other hand every pixel of the texture is treated the same way once, and I'm writing to an OpenGL texture in the usual 8-bit/channel RGB(A) format, so nothing very fancy.

In case you're wondering why I want to ditch OpenCL it's for two reasons, graphics drivers tend to handle running kernels with pauses at regular intervals (like 60 FPS) in ways that are wasteful of the CPU (using as much CPU for the same load no matter if you run at 400 FPS or slow it down to 25 because of wasteful polling in the driver threads), but more importantly because I'm using emscripten to make JavaScript builds and since WebCL support is pretty much nonexistent and not foreseeably happening it would be best to stick strictly to WebGL. And it just seems like maybe what I want to do would be better done with OpenGL.

Comment: `graphics drivers tend to handle running kernels with pauses at regular intervals (like 60 FPS) ` isnt this a driver issue? i run a kernel for 30 seconds and it gets stuck computing it

Comment: Looks like something that fits nicely into a fragment shader to me. Or you could translate it almost 1:1 into a compute shader.

Comment: WebGL doesn't support compute shaders yet.